# Two legend markers, one legend label?

Tags: formatting, legending, labeling

Does anyone know if it is possible within the LineLegend command to have one label for two types of lines? My legend code is here:

```
CombinedLegend = 
 LineLegend[{White, White, Directive[Black, Thickness[0.001]], 
   Directive[Dashed, Black, Thickness[0.001]]}, {MaTeX[
    "\\alpha_\\theta\\text{ (Numerical)}"], 
   MaTeX["\\alpha_\\phi\\text{ (Numerical)}"], 
   MaTeX["\\text{Theoretical}"], MaTeX["\\text{Theoretical}"]}, 
  LegendMarkers -> {{Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Opacity[1]}], 
   FaceForm[], Disk[]}], 
     0.05}, {Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Opacity[1]}], FaceForm[], 
       Rectangle[]}], 0.05}, None, None}, Spacings -> 0.3]
```

So I basically want to combine the label for the last two elements into one titled "theory" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to play a bit with the dimensions etc., but this should get you started:

```
CombinedLegend = 
 LineLegend[{White, White, White, White},
   {MaTeX["\\alpha_\\theta\\text{ (Numerical)}"], 
   MaTeX["\\alpha_\\phi\\text{ (Numerical)}"], 
   Rotate[MaTeX["\\text{Theoretical}"], 0.05]},
  LegendMarkers -> {
    {Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Opacity[1]}], FaceForm[], Disk[]}], 
     0.05},
    {Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Opacity[1]}], FaceForm[], 
       Rectangle[]}], 0.05},
    {Graphics[{Black, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], Dashed, 
       Line[{{0, 0.2}, {1, 0.2}}]}, AspectRatio -> 0.5], 0.05},
    None}, Spacings -> 0.3, LegendMarkerSize -> {10, 10, 40}]
```

Output: (I don't have the `MaTeX` package)

[image]

The idea is to make a single marker that draws both lines (the size of this double marker is made bigger using the element wise `LegendMarkerSize` option). Then we can simply do whatever we want to the label (e.g. rotate it accordingly).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the option `LegendLayout` with a custom layout function:

```
gF = Module[{grid = #}, grid[[-1, 2]] = SpanFromAbove; 
    Grid[grid, Alignment -> {Center, Center},  Spacings -> {Automatic, {0, -2 -> -3}}]] &;

CombinedLegend = LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue, Directive[Orange, Dashed]}, 
{Row[{ToExpression["\\alpha_\\theta", TeXForm],  " (Numerical)"}], 
   Row[{ToExpression["\\alpha_\\phi", TeXForm], " (Numerical)"}], 
   "Theoretical", ""}, "Spacings" -> 0.1, LegendMarkerSize -> 50, 
  LegendLayout -> gF]
```

[image]

Using the example in OP

```
LineLegend[{White, White, Directive[Black, Thickness[0.001]], 
  Directive[Dashed, Black, Thickness[0.001]]}, 
 {Row[{ToExpression["\\alpha_\\theta", TeXForm],  " (Numerical)"}], 
  Row[{ToExpression["\\alpha_\\phi", TeXForm], " (Numerical)"}], 
  "Theoretical", "Theoretical"}, 
 LegendMarkers -> {{Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Opacity[1]}], 
      FaceForm[], Disk[]}], 0.05}, 
    {Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Opacity[1]}], FaceForm[], Rectangle[]}], 0.05}, 
  None, None}, 
 LegendLayout -> (Module[{grid = #}, grid[[-1, 2]] = SpanFromAbove; 
     Grid[grid, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
     Spacings -> {Automatic, {.3, -2 -> -.5}}]] &)]
```

[image]